How to output the result in macos assembly programm?
I was given the task to write a program for arm mac in assembly language. The program should output the sum of the array elements that are greater than a given number. During the creation process I encountered a problem with the output of the result from the w4 register.
Here is the code:
.data
crit: .word 3
numsl: .word 6
nums: .word 1, 1, 1, 4, -5, 9
buffer: .space 20  // Буфер для хранения строки числа

.text
.global _start

_start:
    // Загрузить значение crit
    adrp x0, crit@PAGE
    add x0, x0, crit@PAGEOFF
    ldr w1, [x0]

    // Загрузить значение numsl
    adrp x2, numsl@PAGE
    add x2, x2, numsl@PAGEOFF
    ldr w2, [x2]

    // Загрузить адрес nums
    adrp x3, nums@PAGE
    add x3, x3, nums@PAGEOFF

    // Инициализировать сумму (w4) нулем
    mov w4, 0

sumiteration:
    ldr w5, [x3], 4         // Загрузить значение из nums и увеличить x3 на 4
    cmp w1, w5              // Сравнить crit с текущим элементом nums
    ble skipsum             // Если crit <= текущий элемент, перейти к skipsum
    add w4, w4, w5          // Добавить текущий элемент к сумме

skipsum:
    subs w2, w2, 1          // Уменьшить счетчик элементов (w2) на 1
    bne sumiteration        // Если счетчик не равен нулю, повторить цикл

    // Преобразование числа в строку
    adrp x0, buffer@PAGE
    add x0, x0, buffer@PAGEOFF
    mov x1, x4              // Переместить значение суммы в x1
    bl int_to_str

    // Вывод числа
    mov x0, #1              // File descriptor 1 (stdout)
    adrp x1, buffer@PAGE
    add x1, x1, buffer@PAGEOFF
    mov x2, #20             // Максимальная длина строки числа
    mov x16, #4     // Номер системного вызова для write в macOS
    svc 0                   // Вызвать системный вызов

    // Завершение программы
    mov x0, #0              // Return code 0
    mov x16, #1     // Номер системного вызова для exit в macOS
    svc 0                   // Вызвать системный вызов

// Простой алгоритм преобразования числа в строку
int_to_str:
    // x0 - адрес буфера
    // x1 - число для преобразования
    mov x2, x1              // Копировать число в x2
    mov x3, #10             // Делитель
    add x0, x0, #19         // Начать с конца буфера
    mov w4, #'0'            // ASCII '0'
    mov w5, 0               // Флаг для отрицательных чисел

    cmp x1, 0
    bge convert_loop        // Если число неотрицательное, пропустить обработку
    neg x2, x1              // Взять абсолютное значение числа
    mov w5, 1               // Установить флаг для отрицательных чисел

convert_loop:
    udiv x6, x2, x3         // x6 = x2 / 10
    msub x7, x6, x3, x2     // x7 = x2 - x6 * 10 (остаток)
    add x7, x7, x4          // Преобразовать остаток в символ
    strb w7, [x0], #-1      // Сохранить символ и перейти назад в буфере
    mov x2, x6              // x2 = x6
    cbz x2, end_conversion  // Если x2 == 0, закончить

    b convert_loop

end_conversion:
    cbz w5, skip_minus      // Если число не было отрицательным, пропустить
    mov w6, #'-'            // ASCII '-'
    strb w6, [x0], #-1      // Сохранить знак минус

skip_minus:
    add x0, x0, #1          // Переместить указатель на начало строки
    ret

Commands that I use to create package:
% as -o task2.o task2.s
% ld -macos_version_min 14.0.0 -o task2 task2.o -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64
% ./task2

And the output that the program produces:
4294967294%  

I expect that output of program will be result sum of certain array elements

how much times and where?

You calculate the sum in w4 (32 bits) but try to print x4 (64 bits). You forgot to sign extend the result which happens to be negative (-2) and printing that using 64 bits will indeed produce 4294967294.

@Jester yes, you're right. But how to do this? Internet has very small amount of ARM Mac Assembly guides so it's really hard to find information about it

One of three things: 1) calculate the sum using 64 bits to start with 2) sign extend the result to 64 bits or 3) change the conversion to use 32 bits

"very small amount of ARM Mac Assembly guides", it's not 'Mac' assembly, it's 'aarch64' assembly, there is definitely no shortage of material regarding that
